# git não comita mudanças de charset

Tags: git, codificação-de-caracteres

Olá,

Criei vários arquivos em ISO-8859-1 mas agora estou convertendo-os para UTF-8.

Porém, o git não identifica esta mudança de codificação e mesmo se eu tentar forçar um commit (adicionando qualquer texto), o charset do arquivo continua o mesmo.

Comment: Como você está fazendo essa "mudança na codificação"?

Comment: @PedroAbreu na verdade eu não fiz nenhuma mudança, apenas abri o arquivo eu salvei. E o próprio Atom perde os caracteres com acentos.

Answer (score 1):

O GIT não altera de nenhum modo a codificação do arquivo.
Se o arquivo estiver em ISO-8859-1 o commit vai grava o arquivo desse modo, mesma coisa para UTF-8.

Quando for feito a conversão de um arquivo o git vai identificar quais caracteres foram alterados e quando você fizer um `git status` o arquivo deve aparecer como alterado. Se não aparecer ou não havia caracteres para serem convertidos, ou o conversão não aconteceu.

Outra possibilidade é que a conversão só esteja alterando o charset do arquivo sem converter os caracteres do mesmo, ai vai continuar na mesma, mesmo o arquivo estando com um charset diferente.

Comment: Olá Marcos, mas não é o GIT quem está alterando. É o Atom. Só de abrir um arquivo em ISO-8859-1 e salvar (mesmo sem mudanças). Textos com acentos ficam desconfigurados. Mas veja bem, estou falando do AtomEditor tudo bem? Obrigado pela ajuda ;)